# Error when trying to update ubuntu using sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates

I am using ubuntu 18.04. When I try to run `sudo apt-get update` I am getting the following error. Can anybody try to help me solve this problem?

```
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi

E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Following this when I try to run `sudo apt-get update` It completed successfully .

Answer (score 0):

First try

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If this does not help you, then try the following.

Check which package causing the problem by this command.

```
sudo dpkg --audit
```

Then reinstall or reconfigure it.

Comment: `sudo apt-get -f install` works fine but `sudo dpkg --audit` doesn't return anything to the terminal.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt update` after `sudo apt -f install`? Still you cannot do `sudo apt update` normally?

Comment: yes I tried `sudo apt-get update` after `sudo apt-get -f install` and it still can't update properly with the above error message. But `sudo apt-get -f install` works fine.

Comment: Tell me the result of this script on on a terminal `if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then echo 'true'; else echo 'false'; fi`
And tell if you have `/dev/null`

Comment: The above command prints `false` to the terminal. And there is no `/dev/null` in my home directory.

Comment: OK, then show me the result of `ls -l /var/lib/command-not-found/` and tell me if you have `/usr/lib/cnf-update-db`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93379/discussion-between-mr-robot-and-samuel-mideksa).

Comment: `ls -l /var/lib/command-not-found/` returns `total 0` and `cd /usr/lib/cnf-update-db` and the command `bash: cd: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: Not a directory` returns `bash: cd: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: Not a directory`.

Comment: `cnf-update-db` is a file. So you can get to know if it exists or not by `cat /usr/lib/cnf-update-db`

Comment: I asked something wrong. Tell me the result of `ls -l /var/lib/ | grep 'command-not-found'` not `ls -l /var/lib/command-not-found/`. Sorry.

Comment: well it returns `drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 ኤፕረ 24  2018 command-not-found` to the command line.

Comment: How about `cat /usr/lib/cnf-update-db`? It said that there is no file?

Comment: Some python code is printed like this`!/usr/bin/python3
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if "--debug" in sys.argv[1:]:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    elif "--verbose" in sys.argv[1:]:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    
    db = CommandNotFound.dbpath
    if not os.access(os.path.dirname(db), os.W_OK):
        print("datbase directory %s not writable" % db)
        sys.exit(0)

    command_files = glob.glob("/var/lib/apt/lists/*Commands-*")
    if len(command_files) > 0:
        col = DbCreator(command_files)
        col.create(db)`

Comment: You have the file. So do `sudo chmod a+w /var/lib/command-not-found/` and `sudo apt update`.

Comment: What does `sudo chmod a+w /var/lib/command-not-found/` do? The same error  `E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code` is getting printed to the terminal. Do I have to delete the file `/var/lib/command-not-found/` after changing mode?

Comment: It means you give permission to write to the directory. 
Can you try this one more time `if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then echo 'true'; else echo 'false';fi` ? if the answer is yes, it means you need to make the file `/dev/null` manually by `touch /dev/null`.
And then try `sudo apt update` again.

Comment: The first command returns `true`. The second goes fine but the `apt-get update` is not working due to some issues.

Comment: Due to the same error?

Comment: sorry I mean due to same error

Comment: To make it sure do `if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi` on a terminal please. If there is no error during it, it means a error exists somewhere else.

Comment: The command that you just wrote raises an error `bash: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: It is giving me the error `bash: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
`

Comment: OK, then we understand that you need python3. Try `sudo apt install python3`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3` works without an error. but when I type `python3 --version` It is raising the above error `bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: I have previously installed Anaconda and removed it from by removing the whole directory using `sudo rm ~/Anaconda3` and removed the line invoking conda in .bashrc file. Was that causing the problem?

Comment: Probably yes. So you need to remove python3 completely first by `sudo apt remove --purge python3` and then reinstall it by `sudo apt install python3`. I hope this solve the problem.

Comment: It gives the following when I try to install python3 again after removing with purge `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution). 
The purge also didn't succeed with the following error `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
`

Comment: Then please try `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: I tried this one `sudo apt --fix-broken install python3` but it is not working `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: Please check what is wrong by `sudo apt-get check`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93446/discussion-on-answer-by-mr-robot-error-when-trying-to-update-ubuntu-using-sudo).